# Как правильно: вас или вам?

Tags: грамотная-речь

вас или вам какое слово правильное когда обращаешся к кому либо?

Comment: Приведите контекст, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

***Вас* или *вам*? Какое слово правильное, когда обращаешься к кому-либо?**

— **Вас** что интересует? **Вам** помочь?

В таком контексте слова, о которых спрашиваете, — на своих местах.

Comment: а если это не вопрос?

Comment: Вас просят отойти в сторонку, извините. (Прошу вас посторониться!) Вам, должно быть, трудно стоять, присаживайтесь! (Вам должно быть стыдно.)

Answer (score 1):

*Вас* и *вам* -- это падежные формы местоимения *вы*. В зависимости от контекста (от глагола) выбирается нужное обращение.